# How to set the default timestamp format for the current session in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb, mariasql, mariadb-10.4

How to set default timestamp format like YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 or 'Month dd, YYYY, HH:MI A.M.' to select queries running in the current session instead of calling DATE_FORMAT on each column through `MySQL` command.

Comment: You can't set in session it's read-only variable, if you want you need to do it in **my.conf**

Answer (score 0):

There is Locale for some formatting tailoring.

But a `TIMESTAMP` column is nearly a date+time; the only control you have is whether to *store* 'fractional' seconds:  `TIMESTAMP(3)`.

You should plan on using `DATE_FORMAT` if Locale does not have what you want.